# Vuex data exists, but JavaScript log error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I use Vuex, get data from a URL, and I want use this data like this in computed in Vue.js. What is the problem?

```
<script>
import {mapGetters, mapActions} from "vuex";
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["ONE_FILM"]),
    allActors() {
        return this.ONE_FILM.actors.split(",")
    },
    allVoiceActors() {
        return this.ONE_FILM.rolesDuplicated.split(",")
    },
}
</script>
```

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWZ7K.png) 
//TypeError: this.ONE_FILM.actors is undefined

My Vuex code looks like this:

```
export default {
    state: {
        oneFilm: {
            actors:[],
            rolesDuplicated:[],
            relatedFilms:[],
            facts:[],
            reviews:[]
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async getFilm({commit}, id) {
            const data = await fetch(URL);
            const dataResponse = await data.json();
            const film = dataResponse.data[id]
            commit("setOneFilmData", film)
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        setOneFilmData(state, film) {
            state.oneFilm = film
        },
    },
    getters: {
        ONE_FILM(state) {
            return state.oneFilm;
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76791129/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the corrected Vuex store with actors and rolesDuplicated as empty strings:

```js
export default {
  state: {
    oneFilm: {
      actors: "", // Initialize as empty string
      rolesDuplicated: "", // Initialize as empty string
      relatedFilms: [],
      facts: [],
      reviews: []
    }
  },
  // ... rest of the code
}
```

With this change, your computed properties in the component should work as expected without any "undefined" errors.

Remember to make sure that the data fetched from the URL is being correctly mapped to the Vuex store so that the state is populated with the actual film data. Ensure that the getFilm action is being called with the correct ID to fetch the film data from the API.

Additionally, if the data fetched from the URL is already an object (not an array), you should update your mutation to merge the fetched film data into the oneFilm property instead of setting it directly:

```js
mutations: {
  setOneFilmData(state, film) {
    state.oneFilm = { ...state.oneFilm, ...film };
  },
},
```